# Zxing not scanning certain Data Matrix codes

Tags: java, image-processing, zxing, barcode-scanner

Hi I am able to read some 2d datamatrix barcode images downloaded from internet using Zxing library but not able to read images taken from my high resolution colored camera images. Now I am converting them into black and white images but still images are not readable. Can someone suggest me where I am doing wrong? I have attached some images here. Please help.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are white-on-black barcodes, and are not standard. The library doesn't read them. You would have to invert the image.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Sean, Is there any possibility to read colored images using Zxing library or we have to invert them, is there any way to invert these images?

Comment: Colored is fine as long as it's dark-on-light. No standard includes light-on-dark as a require type of barcode to scan, so these shouldn't really be used. You just flip dark for light. Any image editor can do it. It's easy to do in Java code too.